# How to solve the following error in Laravel and How to know the File Path of SessionHandlerInterface?

Tags: laravel

I started working with Laravel. Faced a **FatalErrorException**:

> Declaration of SessionHandlerInterface::1($save_path, $session_name) must be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface::1($maxlifetime)
>   *in FileSessionHandler.php line 10*

It was working yesterday, and as far as I remember, I have not updated anything.
I tried to look into file `FileSessionHandler` but I can't figure out the problem. I also tried to look for `SessionHandlerInterface`, but I am not able to find the Interface file.

**How can I solve this problem?**
Also please tell me the meaning of 1 after scope resolution operator.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I just restarted XAMPP. But I dont understand, what might be the issue?

Comment: maybe your browser had session data stored whose MAXLIFETIME must have expired. If same error occurs , try to clear browsers memory to see if it works?

Comment: @BILALMALIK, It was not the issue with browser cache. I tried that too. Thanks. Can you elaborate the error meaning?

Comment: I still think that your parameter of SessionHandlerInterface::1($save_path, $session_name)  = save_path or session_name OR SessionHandlerInterface::1($maxlifetime) might not have values for the first time  Let see tomorrow if you receive the same error..

Comment: @BILALMALIK yes, it might be so. **Thanks!**